# How to select data depending on other table row values?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables: "Factory" and "Store"

```
Factory 
id (P.K.) 
specialCode 
...


Store
id (P.K.)
factory (F.K.)
...
```

I need to select the stores, which factory has specialCode "9" (it's an integer value). How can I do this?
I need something like `select * from store where factory.specialCode=9` How can I get the values of foreign table row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply Join at the referenced columns

```
SELECT 
   s.*,f.* 
from store S 
INNER JOIN  Factory  f ON s.factory  = f.id  WHERE f.specialCode=9
```

Comment: What is `SELECT s.*.f.*`? Do you mean `SELECT s.*, f.*`? (Simply `SELECT *` in this case)

Comment: you are right the muist be a comma between the twi s.*,f.* to get all columns of both tables

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `EXISTS`:

```
select s.*
from store s 
where exists (select 1 from factory f where f.id = s.factory and f.specialCode = '9')
```

Comment: what `s.*` does? What is the difference between usual `select * from...` and this method?